# Adding for loop inside click event

Tags: jquery

I am having 5 checkboxes,when i click each check box percentage should be increased similarly when i uncheck the checkbox percentage should be decreased.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var arr=['c','f','i','n','s'];
        var n=6;
            $("input").click(function(){
            if(this.checked){
            if($.inArray(this.value,arr)>-1){
                for(var count=1;count<n;count++)
                { 

                  var percentage=Math.ceil(count * (100/5));
                  alert('your percentage is' + percentage);
                }
            }else{}}
            });

});
```

But it is returning 100% for a single click.What i am doing wrong?

Comment: show html code also or add plunker

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x4bb87L4/

Comment: why are you using checkboxes to do what radios are intended to be used for?

Comment: @charlietfl Nothing i am just practicing examples to learn jquery

Comment: check the answer provided by me , should work perfectly for you

Comment: Thanks Guys.Really this stack overflow is helping me to learn more:-)thanks all:-):-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check updated fiddle [jsfiddle.net/x4bb87L4/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/x4bb87L4/3/)

Code that updated

```
    $(document).ready(function(){       
      var arr=['c','f','i','n','s']; 

      $("input").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false).next().removeClass("fa-times cross fa-check tick");

        if(this.checked){
            if($.inArray(this.value,arr)>-1){                                                   
                $(this).next().addClass("fa-check tick");           
            }else{                                                        
               $(this).next().addClass("fa-times cross");           
            }                 
        }else{
            $(this).next().removeClass("fa-check times tick cross");
        }

        var correctAnswer=$(".fa-check.tick").length;
        //var wrongAnswer=$(".fa-times.cross").length;
        //var count=correctAnswer-wrongAnswer;
        var count=correctAnswer;
        count=count<0?0:count;
        $('#value').html(count);
        var percentage=Math.ceil(count * (100/5));
        percentage=percentage<0? 0 :percentage;
        $('#percent').html(percentage);

    });             
 });
```

Comment: Have you seen above fiddle? Is it possible to decrease percentage when i click wrong answer?i.e i have to allocate only 20 percent per row .when i click correct answer percentage should be increased when i click wrong answer percentage should be decreased

Comment: yes I have updated fiddle code. Check it https://jsfiddle.net/x4bb87L4/2/

Comment: I am getting wrong answer:-( i said i need to allocate only 20 percent per row,But it checks all check boxes.Can you please check again?

Comment: Yes let me check it

Comment: I have updated logic as per you told. You can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/x4bb87L4/3/

Answer (score 1):

According to me this should be done by creating an other array like

```
var n=0;
  var arrayforselection=[];
        $("input").click(function(){
        if(this.checked){

  if($.inArray(this.value,arrayforselection)<0){
  if($.inArray(this.value,arr)>-1){
  arrayforselection.push(this.value);
  }
  }
  }else{

  if($.inArray(this.value,arrayforselection)>=0){
  if($.inArray(this.value,arr)>-1){
  arrayforselection.indexOf(this.value)
  arrayforselection.splice(arrayforselection.indexOf(this.value),1);
  }
  }
  }
  n=arrayforselection.length;
        if($.inArray(this.value,arr)>-1){
  if(n===0){
             $('#value').html(n)
              var percentage=Math.ceil(n * (100/5));
              $('#percent').html(percentage)

  }
            for(var count=1;count<=n;count++)
            {
              $('#value').html(count)
              var percentage=Math.ceil(count * (100/5));
              $('#percent').html(percentage)
            }
        }else{

  }
        });
```

the previous selected Answer will not work in you multiple times check and unchecked the correct answer , it will increase the percentage and will not decrease it . Find the [**Updated Jsfiddel**](https://jsfiddle.net/62q6co15/2/) here

Comment: Ok i will check